# vim: reverse foreground and background colors for colorcolumn

Tags: vim

Is there a way to tell vim to reverse the fore and background colors it is currently using?  For example, I have `colorcolumn` set to 101, which currently just changes the background of the 101st column to white.  The issue is it doesn't change the foreground color, so when the foreground is white or yellow or some other light color, I can't see the character in the 101st column.  I'm wondering if instead `colorcolumn` can be set to reverse the foreground and background colors of whatever text is in the 101st column.

Alternatively, can `colorcolumn` be set to simply draw a 1px white line between columns 100 and 101,

Answer (score 4):

yes, you can define a group with `{key}=reverse....` something like

```
:hi ColorColumn gui=reverse cterm=reverse
```

Doc:

```
:h inverse
```

Comment: this reversed the foreground color, but not the background.  i.e. the original color was yellow on black, and `colorcolumn` was white, this resulted in the 101st column being white on yellow, as opposed to black on yellow

Comment: I discovered that you can set `cterm=reverse` AND `ctermbg=black`.  when I did that, I got black on the previous foreground color.  The issue now becomes that in the rare case that black IS the previous foreground color, the colorcolumn becomes black on black.